# Admin products grid - multi selection doesn't work In Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4, product-grid, multiselect-attribute

We use Magento 2.4.6-p3, php8.2...
I want to do mass edit of products attributes in backend grid.

- After choosing select All - confirmation is visible saying for example: 7565 records found (7565 selected).
- So, I select Update attribute, do editing and click Save.

Unfortunately only first in the line/grid product which is "checked/ticked" has changes saved. Result says: "Task "Update attributes for 7565 selected products": 76 item(s) have been successfully updated."
Every 100 item is updated?

Or if I select only 2 products, result is: Task "Update attributes for 2 selected products": 1 item(s) have been successfully updated.

How to fix it?

EDIT:
It seems like magento selects every 100 item. If I select 200 products, only 2 are updated. Selected 300, make 3 products updated and so on...